# Code Cleanup for Combining Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I do not have much experience with VBA but I will start by explaining my situation.

I have a workbook with 341 sheets. Each sheet is identical in layout in that they occupy the space A1:J48. I need to combine all of these into one sheet called "COMBINATION". The information of relevance is from A10:J48. I also need to have the cells from A1:J9 as they are the title which is shared across all the sheets.

What I did was write a code that copies A1:J48 for Sheet1 (to get the title and info) and pastes it into "COMBINATION" with the paste special as text, then a code that goes to Sheet2 and copies from A10:J48 and pastes it in the first empty cell in column A of "COMBINATION".

This brings me to my problem. I have realized that there must be an easier way of doing this instead of copying the code 339 more times for each of the sheets.

See below the code. It does what I want correctly but as mentioned, I would like to find a way to not do this 339 more times...

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1:J48").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("COMBINATION").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A10:J10").Select
Range("J10").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("COMBINATION").Select
NextFree = Range("A10:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use code like the following:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Long

'Copy A1:J9 from the first sheet
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J9").Copy
WorkSheets("COMBINATION").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                   Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                   SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                                   Transpose:=False

'Now loop through every sheet (except "COMBINATION") copying cells A10:J48

r = 10  ' first sheet will be copied to row 10 in COMBINATION
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "COMBINATION" Then
        ws.Range("A10:J48").Copy
        Worksheets("COMBINATION").Range("A" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                              Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                              SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                                              Transpose:=False

        'Set pointer ready for next sheet
        r = r + 39
    End If
Next

'Set column widths
Worksheets("COMBINATION").Columns.AutoFit
```

If your sheets don't always have data in all 39 rows (10 to 48), replace `r = r + 39` with

```
r = Worksheets("COMBINATION").Range("A" & Worksheets("COMBINATION").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. I tried your code and it copies and pastes correctly except that it only starts pasting data at A49. This means there is a gap between the info pasted from A10:J48. At A49, the information from Sheet1 pastes and then the rest follows suit. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Update, I tried replacing r = r+39 as you mentioned and it fixed the above issue...thanks!

Comment: (a) Do you have a sheet (other than "COMBINATION") that has blanks in cells A10:J48?  (b) Is the "COMBINATION" sheet actually named "COMBINATION", or is it perhaps named "Combination"?

Comment: If your "COMBINATION" sheet is actually called "Combination", the alternative method of calculating `r` will work only **as long as "Combination" is the first sheet processed**.  If the incorrect name is what was causing the blanks to be placed into the results, the correct way to fix the error would be to change the `If` statement to correctly reflect the name of the sheet which is to be ignored.

Comment: My "COMBINATION" sheet is exactly as "COMBINATION". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put the repeating code into a loop (untested):

```
Dim i as Integer

For i=2 to 341
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("A10:J10").Select
    Range("J10").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("COMBINATION").Select
    NextFree = Range("A10:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    Range("A" & NextFree).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is convenient but slow.  It is much faster to define your 'Target' range to be the same size as your source range and do a direct assignment.

```
Sub CombineData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Range
    With Worksheets("COMBINATION")
        .Range("A1:J9").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J49").Value
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> .Name Then
                Set Target = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Target.Resize(39, 10).Value = ws.Range("A10:J48").Value
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```